# Match Regex Only at the Start/End of a String

Tags: javascript, regex

As per the title, I'm trying to use a .match() function on a string to only match with instances that occur at the start or end of that string (but no where in the middle).

For example, on the word "test":

```
x = "1 TEST 1"
x1 = "TEST 1"
x2 = "1 TEST"
x3 = "TEST"
```

Only x1, x2 and x3 should match the regex. Currently, I have:

```
.toUpperCase().match(/(TEST)/)
```

Which will match every instance of "test". I've tried using the ^ and $ modifiers, but they'll only match x3. This one however:`

```
.toUpperCase().match(/(TEST)$/)
```

Will match x2 and x3 only, with `.toUpperCase().match(/^(TEST)/)` matching x1 and x3 only.

Answer (score 6):

Just match one or the other using `|`.

`.toUpperCase().match(/^TEST|TEST$/)`

Also note that you don't need to put parentheses around `TEST`.

Comment: It may depend a bit on your use case, but you could skip the `.toUpperCase()`, and just make the match case insensitive: `.match(/^TEST|TEST$/i)`

Comment: Thanks for the help CAustin! And that's a great tip regarding case-sensitivity @benschumacher , thank you as well

Answer (score 0):

```
/^TEST.*|.*TEST$/
```

this regex will match a line if it starts or ends with "TEST". add `m` to match multiple lines

Note: this regex will return the whole line